# UICollection with Checkbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, checkbox, uicollectionview

Hi i am working with camera app , captured picture are shown in `thumbnail-view` using collection view ,i have used `checkbox` to select the particular picture,Example, i taken three picture , i just tapping on 1st and 2nd picture to select it will get selected ,then i am taking another two picture ,now the `checkbox` image moved to the latest picture ,i don't know why it happens ,
i have done this in collection view cell class , and i have created a `Boolean` property in same class it itself.

```
- (IBAction)checkButton:(id)sender {

if(!checked)
{
    [self.checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    checked = YES;


}
else if (checked)
{
    [self.checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    checked = NO;

}}
```

please help me to do this ,

Comment: Are you using `checked` as a static variable?

Comment: Please show your code for creating cells.

Comment: it is possible to send a whole code here ?

Answer (score 0):

If `checked` is declared as `static`, then there is only one of them which is shares by every instance of your class.  You should use a property instead.

Comment: Thanks Jeff Wolksi , checked is a boolean property

Comment: @interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    BOOL checked;
    
} Like this only i have created a boolean property